# How to measure inductance (and more) of DIY LF (125kHz) RFID antennas

Tags: rfid

When winding my own coil two factors seem most important, inductance and serial resistance of my antenna.

However measuring inductance doesn't seem that easy. Ideally I need an LCR-meter that is able to measure inductance at 125kHz for best accuracy. However looking around LCR-meters seem to stop around 1kHz.

How will my measurement accuracy suffer if the LCR meter only measures at 1kHz?

My current model has a variance of ~0.2mH just switching between 100Hz and 1kHz mesaurement frequency, however it is a rather cheap model (PeakTech 2175).

When looking for a new measurement device I might as well at look something a bit more fancy. I can imagine that coil capacitance might be interesting if not too relevant. Anyway, any suggestions on what to look for?

Comment: What were the inductance measurements at 100 Hz and 1 kHz?

Comment: 2.055mH @ 1kHz (11uH range) and 2.17mH @ 100Hz (110uH range). For one of the antennas.

Comment: Why measure on different ranges (11 and 110 uH)?

Comment: The LCR-meter has fixed measurement frequencies for different ranges. Inititally just out of curiosity. The antenna in question, has a manufacturer rating of 2.8mH which fits into the measured resonance frequency of my RFID reader, so the LCR-meter is wrong either way.

Answer (score 1):

For a resonant circuit like an RFID antenna, you could also do a sweep with a frequency generator and measure the resonant frequency of the circuit with a scope.